# Java: easily peek backwards or forwards in a list

Tags: java, list, iterator, lexical-analysis

I'm coding a lexical analyzer in java and need to look backwards or forwards easily in a list of custom datatypes (my tokens). I've tried saving the next and previous item as a copy, but then I figured out that I need to look arbitrarily far ahead or back. I then tried to use an index, but it was beyond unpleasant to debug that since I had to think about decreasing, increasing and getting the current position in a pinch (I even had the objects store an int of where they were at) all the while keeping within range of the list, so it was an ugly, hard to read mess of spaghetti code too at that.

I then looked into [linked lists](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_linkedlist_class.htm), but they don't quite work like I want them too. I want a node and I want to be able to look ahead for two or three positions, or back, and I didn't really find any good tools for that at that place.

Right now, I'm trying out [iterators](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_using_iterator.htm) but I have the same problem as with indexes: I have to decrease and increase back again to where I was at since next() moves the cursor instead of just "peeking ahead".

I'm thinking of coding my own linked list and just hitting `node.next().next()` if I want to go two steps forward, or a loop repeatedly hitting it if I want to go longer than that. Is there any built in way in Java saving me from this?

Comment: Your choice of data structure isn't the problem (should just be List IMO for easiest random access). You are looking for an API that doesn't exist. You need to inherit from List and create a class that hides some of these uglier implementation details from your lexer code.

Comment: If you really are implementing a "lexical analyzer" you shouldn't be needing look-back and look-ahead: a finite state machine should do the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting spaghetti code because you're not following [SoC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns). One way to help yourself is to create a specialized collection class that implements functions which, for your problem domain, hide the ugly particulars of array navigation such as tracking the current position, iterating N steps back and forth, "peeking" back and forth, etc.

There are a hundred ways to do this but in my code sample below I chose to compose with rather than extend the `ArrayList<>` class. I chose `ArrayList<>` because of its random access capabilities and chose not to extend to help stay away from manipulating the `ArrayList<>` directly from client code and getting back into a spaghetti mess. I wasn't considering performance but as it happens that `ArrayList<>`'s random access functions are mostly O(1) rather than O(n) which you would get if you used an iterator or linked list. With those collection types you would also be forced to traverse through the collection just to peek at an object which hurts performance further and also makes implementation that much harder.

Here is [a link to an Ideone implementation](http://ideone.com/mI66No) of my suggested solution. It is a bit different from the code shown below due to the complexities imposed by an online Java compiler but the code is easily accessible and fully executable.

Code sample notes: This is a full, working sample which contain three classes necessary to demostrate the concepts. There is a class to hold the `main` function which demonstrates usage of the collection class and also acts as a poor-man's unit test. There is a [POJO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_Old_Java_Object)-style class to represent a node or token and finally the utility class which exposes a specialized set of functions, or API. The code is very basic and naive. There is no error or bounds checking of any kind but it demonstrates my suggestion fairly well, IMHO.

To the code! Here is the main function which initializes the `NodeList` with an arbitrary, Java-like line of code and then proceeds to peek and move in the token list. Note that there is no variable needed in the client code to track what's going on. The navigation is all handled within the `NodeList` class. The client code's concerns now do not include that ugliness.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class TestNodeList {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // usage: basic initialization
    NodeList nl = new NodeList();
    nl.add(new Node("someUtilObj")); 
    nl.add(new Node("."));
    nl.add(new Node("print"));
    nl.add(new Node("("));
    nl.add(new Node("myIntValue"));
    nl.add(new Node(")"));
    nl.add(new Node(";"));
    nl.print();

    // usage: using the API, moving and peeking
    nl.peekAhead(1).print();
    nl.peekAhead(2).print();
    nl.peekAhead(3).print();
    nl.moveAhead(2).print();
    nl.getCurrentNode().print();
    nl.peekBack(2).print();
  }
}
```

This is the implementation of the specialized collection with some fields and functions I assume would be useful for your lexical analysis. Again, it is quite bare but covers the more important concepts.

```
public class NodeList {
  private ArrayList<Node> nodeList = new ArrayList<Node>();
  private int currentNodeIndex = 0;

  public void add(Node node) {
    nodeList.add(node);
  }
  // Node is private/read-only - currentNode should only be set by internal operations
  public Node getCurrentNode() { 
    return nodeList.get(currentNodeIndex);
  }

  // moving back and forth
  public Node moveAhead(int count) { 
    currentNodeIndex += count;
    return nodeList.get(currentNodeIndex);
  }
  public Node moveBack(int count) { 
    currentNodeIndex -= count;
    return nodeList.get(currentNodeIndex);
  } 

  // peeking back and forth
  public Node peekAhead(int count) {
    return nodeList.get(currentNodeIndex + count);
  }
  public Node peekBack(int count) {
      return nodeList.get(currentNodeIndex - count);
  }

  public void print() {
    for (int i=0; i<nodeList.size(); i++) {
      System.out.print(nodeList.get(i).getToken());
    }
    System.out.println("");
  }
}
```

Other functions to consider implementing for a better, cleaner API:

- `peekNext()` - same as `peekAhead(1)` but w/o the magic number. I would think that this would also be the most frequently called function in your specialized collection so it makes sense to have a shorter, cleaner version of the operation than `peekAhead(1)`
- `peekPrev()` - same as `peekBack(1)` but w/o the magic number
- `moveNext()` - same as `moveAhead(1)` but w/o the magic number. This would also be a frequently called function in your API and a cleaner version of `moveAhead(1)`
- `movePrev()` - same as `moveBack(1)` but w/o the magic number
- `peekAt(int)` - Peek at an element at a specific index in the collection
- `jumpTo(int)` - Move current position to an element at a specific index in the collection
- `moveFirst()` - Resets your current position to the 0th element in the collection

Here are a few more but I'm not sure they would be very useful:

- `moveLast()` - Sets current position to the last element in the collection
- `peekFirst()` - Peek at the 0th element in the collection
- `peekLast()` - Peek at the last element in the collection

To properly implement the functions listed above you should stay consistent and treat them almost like overloads. So, for example, internally `peekNext()` would actually just call `peekAhead(1)`. This would keep your API's behavior consistent and simpler to maintain in case the implementation of the core function, `peekAhead`, needs to change.

And finally, here's the POJO. It just contains a single field, the token value, and a function to help write the value to console. Notice that the class does not have an index to itself because it isn't necessary.

```
// Your node/token class
public class Node {
  private String token;
  public Node(String token) {
    this.token = token;
  }
  public String getToken() {
    return token;
  }
  public void print() {
    System.out.println(token);
  }
}
```

Comment: Wow, bravo!  I was not expecting such a thorough and well thought-out answer here.  Kudos.  I'm probably going to borrow your implementation (and credit you), even though I could have done it myself.

Answer (score 1):

For traversing forward and backwards you can use ListIterator instead of Iterator. You can get it from the LinkedList:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#listIterator(int)